# Getting JSON values in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json document (as_stats.json) that looks something like this:

`{"failed":5, "received": {"192.168.5.2": 40, "192.168.5.45": 84, "127.0.0.1": 145}}`

My python code looks like this:

```
import json,urllib
data = open('as_stats.json').read()
d = json.loads(data)

for x in d['received']:
    if (x != '127.0.0.1'):
        print x
```

The values returned are the IP addresses, which are variables i.e. the could change any time to any other address. What I am interested in is the number of files received from each IP address as well. When I try rewriting my code as

```
for x,y in d['received']:
        if (x <> '127.0.0.1'):
            print x,y
```

I get a message saying "too many values to unpack".

How do I go about getting the values that I want from the key-value pairs?

Comment: That's severely invalid JSON.

Comment: Use `!=` to compare inequality. The `<>` syntax is obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
for x,y in d['received'].iteritems():
```

Normal iteration over a dict will give you only the keys. Use `itervalues` to get the values, or `iteritems` to get both keys and values.

Comment: Or you can do `for x in d['received']: print x, d['received'][x]` or still `for x,y in d['received'].items(): print x,y`. It is worth noting that `iteritems()` returns an iterator, while `items()` returns a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks kind people. I have made the JSON valid, although that wasn't the problem, minitech and used the more up-to-date operand Colin. 

Thanks again @interjay. I'm doing python for the first time and it's been ages since I last did some coding :-)